# Como instalar via composer una version antigua de un paquete

Tags: php, laravel, composer, libreria

estoy usando laravel 8 y PHP 7.4, necesito integrar una librería para tomar capturas de pantalla, desgraciadamente todas las que he probado requieren de PHP 8, cosa que por cuestiones de trabajo y externas no tengo permitido actualizar, encontré que la versión 3.40.2 de [browsershot](https://packagist.org/packages/spatie/browsershot) soporta PHP 7.1+ pero no sé cómo obtener el paquete de esa versión

También me serviría alguna recomendación de una librería para tomar un screenshot web usando laravel 8 y php 7.4

cuando uso `composer require spatie/browsershot` tengo el problema por la versión de PHP

Gracias de antemano :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para instalar una versión específica de un paquete con composer primero debes buscar el nombre del paquete y el número de versión en [packagist](https://packagist.org/), el comando para instalarlo desde consola sería:

```
composer require vendor/package:version
```

en tu caso para el paquete [browsershot](https://packagist.org/packages/spatie/browsershot):

```
composer require spatie/browsershot:3.40.2
```

o agregando tambien en tu archivo `composer.json` la respectiva versión del paquete:

```
{
    "require": {
        "spatie/browsershot" : "3.40.2"
    }
}
```

y ejecutando:

```
composer install
```

<sup>PD: Puedes ir probando con diferentes versiones hasta obtener la correcta.</sup>